# fish - Print array/list on multiline

Tags: echo, fish

I want to print an array where each element is on a line so I can pipe it to other tools.

Example:

```
> set foo "A 1" "B 3" "C 9"
> echo $foo
A 1 B 3 C 9                     <-- Not clear what the elements are!
> for i in $foo; echo $i; end;  <-- Too verbose for working
```

Note: using `tr/sed/string join` is not the solution I'm looking for there is no guarantee that any element will not contain a ~~newline~~ or space/tab char.

Comment: If you want to pipe to other tools, those tools read line-wise and your list elements can contain newlines your format is already broken! There is already no way those tools will be able to reconstruct your elements.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: using tr/sed/string join is not the solution I'm looking for there is no guarantee that any element will not contain a newline or space char.

If your elements can contain a newline, printing each element on a line is *already* broken.

E.g.

```
set foo a\nb c
```

You *can* print this with

```
printf %s\n $foo
```

but it will result in

```
a
b
c
```

so whatever command you pipe it has no idea that "a\nb" is one element.

Like others have said, to *show* what a variable contains for yourself you can use `set --show foo` or something like

```
printf '|%s|\n' $foo
```

but that won't work when passing it to a command because it has no idea what your format is.

You need to rethink your data format or pass the data as arguments, not via stdin. What you need to do exactly depends on which command you are calling and what it's supposed to do.

If your command has a switch to read null-delimited input, you can use `string join0` like

```
 string join0 $foo | baz --read0
```

For example if $foo is a list of files and you want to use `du` on them

```
 string join0 $foo | du --files0-from=-
```

Although in that case you could also pass them as arguments directly like so

```
 du $foo
```

Comment: Yes you are right about the new line. I might have included that pre-maturely (my requirement was only spaces). e.g. `set cwd_la (ls -la)` then you have the columns with space/tabs. I'm actually suprised it didn't create a 2D array as fish treats space as next element when setting vars.

Comment: Fish does not have 2d arrays, and it doesn't split command substitutions on spaces or tabs, only newlines.

Answer (score 2):

To inspect the contents of a variable `set -S foo` or `set --show foo` is nice.

```
set foo "A 1" "B 3" "C 9" "element
with
newlines"
set -S foo
```

shows

```
$foo: set in global scope, unexported, with 3 elements
$foo[1]: |A 1|
$foo[2]: |B 3|
$foo[3]: |C 9|
$foo[4]: |element\nwith\nnewlines|
```

This is fish v3.2.0 -- earlier versions have a bit more verbose detail, I recall.

---

Or, `printf` with some start/end markers:

```
$ printf '>>%s<<\n' $foo
>>A 1<<
>>B 3<<
>>C 9<<
>>element
with
newlines<<
```

Comment: Earlier versions will also explicitly tell you which scopes it's *not* in, so you'll get a bunch of "not set in local scope" and "not set in universal scope". This wasn't useful so we dropped it in 3.2.

Comment: OMG! How have I never known about `-S`. I just read the docs ofr `set` ages ago and never thought about new features.

Comment: Not really a new feature.  Just that the new release truncates the output a bit to make it even more useful, but `set --show` has been a great command for a while now ;-).  That said, it's output isn't that great for piping into another command -- I'd go with the `printf` form for that.